# Shell command for sending a Mac OS X "Message"?

Tags: macos, sms, osx-lion

I have Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.x)  and though I appreciate the "messages" feature through the GUI, I'm trying to find a way to send an iMessage to another person's phone via the command line.   Does anyone know how to do this?

I'd prefer not rigging a script with "open Messages.app", but respect if that's the only way currently possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send "Hello World" to buddy "(your buddy name)"'
```

Comment: This is still working on macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way to do this. if you have brew installed, simply run 'brew install iMessage'. then run 'iMessage -t yourmessage -c contact@email.com'.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible the apple developer site doesn't mention that and probably it's because they don't want to give opportunity to programmatically send messages (i think spambots are a concern) because it could be potentially annoying to receive automated messages but you could use notifications that it's specifically thinked to do what you are asking